# is there a npm equivalent of bower pluggable resolvers

Tags: npm, bower

Bower provides a very powerful plugin architecture for path resolvers to support bower packages installation from custom paths.

https://bower.io/docs/pluggable-resolvers/

https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1649

Is there any such equivalent in npm?

Answer (score 1):

There exists at least one package for npm with that functionality:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pnpm/npm-resolver
- https://github.com/pnpm/npm-resolver

So the functionality never seems being built-in but it can be added as package.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though the resolver is not very powerful and also lacks documentation - but it is a good start to look. I will award the bounty to you without accepting the answer.

Comment: Thank's, yes I remarked missing documentation. If you never find another resolver, perhaps you can hack the one.

Comment: @ArshabhAgarwal What do you think about https://github.com/mjeanroy/bower-npm-resolver ?

Comment: @ArshabhAgarwal the `@pnpm/npm-resolver` is used by the [pnpm](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm) package manager, so it is very reliable. I can add more docs to the repo but it has typings, so if you use typescript of VS code, autocompletion should work well.

Comment: also, if it is not powerful enough, you can check other resolvers/fetchers of pnpm. Feel free to write in our [chatroom](https://gitter.im/pnpm/pnpm) as well